# store two for loop output in a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D matrix ‘DATA’ whose dimension is 100(L)X200(B)X50(H). The values are random for each   grid point.
I want to the find the  number of points where the values are between 10 and 20 in each vertical column. The output will be a 2D matrix. 
For this I used the following code:

```
out = []
for i in range(np.shape(DATA)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(DATA)[1]):
        a = DATA[i,j,:]
        b = a[(a>25) & (a<30)]
        c = len(b)
        out.append(c)
```

but I am not getting the 2D matrix. Instead I am getting an array
Please Help

Comment: It stores the output in an array not matrix

Comment: I want the output to be a 2D matrix of dimension 100X200

Comment: `out` is a list, starting as `[]` and growing with each `append`.  Specifically it will be a list of numbers, since what you append is `c`, the length of `b`.  You can of course turn that list into an array, though it will be 1d.  Why do you want a 2d output?

Comment: because I want a contour plot for 'out'

Comment: Why are you collecting values in a flat list?  Why not a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `out` as a list, and appending each value. Here's a quick modification to your code that should give you the desired result:

```
out = []
for i in range(np.shape(DATA)[0]):
    out.append([])  # make a second dim for each i
    for j in range(np.shape(DATA)[1]):
        a = DATA[i,j,:]
        b = a[(a>25) & (a<30)]
        c = len(b)
        out[i].append(c)
```

The change is that I made `out` a `list` of `list`s. In each iteration over `i`, we append a new `list`. Then in the inner loop, we append values to the list at index `i`.

**Update**

If you want an `numpy.ndarray` instead, you can modify your code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
out = np.ndarray(np.shape(DATA))  # initialize to the desired shape
for i in range(np.shape(DATA)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(DATA)[1]):
        a = DATA[i,j,:]
        b = a[(a>25) & (a<30)]
        c = len(b)
        out[i][j] = c
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to leverage `numpy` functionality:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(100,200,50))

range_sum = np.sum(np.logical_and(np.less_equal(data, 20),
                                  np.greater_equal(data, 10)
                                  ), axis=-1)

range_sum.shape
Out[6]: (100, 200)

range_sum
Out[7]: 
array([[11, 12, 12, ..., 13,  9, 10],
       [ 6, 12, 11, ..., 10, 14,  5],
       [11, 11, 16, ..., 10, 12, 15],
       ..., 
       [11, 17,  9, ..., 12, 12, 11],
       [ 9,  8, 10, ...,  7, 15, 12],
       [12, 10, 11, ..., 12, 11, 19]])
```